# request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs failed

Tags: javascript, npm

I am unable to download any package from npm. Its showing request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:14077419:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert access denied:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:802 Below is the complete log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with 
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm- 
cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'yargs@4.8.1',
1 verbose cli   '--save' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.11.1
4 verbose npm-session 0a37c58aac4a7e6c
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for yargs@4.8.1 request to 
https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs failed, reason: write EPROTO 
101057795:error:14077419:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert 
access denied:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:802:
8 verbose type system
9 verbose stack FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs 
failed, reason: write EPROTO 101057795:error:14077419:SSL 
routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert access 
denied:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:802:
9 verbose stack
9 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.req.on.err (C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\node_modules\make-fetch- 
happen\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\index.js:68:14)
9 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
9 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
9 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
9 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
9 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
9 verbose stack     at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:418:12)
9 verbose stack     at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:440:5)
9 verbose stack     at _destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:39:7)
9 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.Socket._destroy (net.js:574:3)
9 verbose stack     at TLSSocket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:32:8)
9 verbose stack     at WriteWrap.afterWrite [as oncomplete] (net.js:882:10)
10 verbose cwd D:\Projects\Weather-App
11 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
12 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "yargs@4.8.1" 
"--save"
13 verbose node v8.11.1
14 verbose npm  v5.6.0
15 error code EPROTO
16 error errno EPROTO
17 error request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs failed, reason: write 
EPROTO 101057795:error:14077419:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 
alert access denied:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:802:
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: can you share your .npmrc file?

Comment: I am on Windows machine.My npmrc file is  prefix=${APPDATA}\npm. if this is not the required file then how to get it

Comment: What is the npm command that you are running?

Comment: npm install yargs@latest --save

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error

```
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/clsx failed, reason: write EPROTO...
```

and after running

```
npm install -g npm
```

no error appeared again